# Allow https access only on Apache?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I want to allow https only on my Apache server on Raspbian, but every time I try to edit the ports.conf in /ect/apache2/ to listen to Port 443 and the sites-available/000-default.conf to:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

the server doesn't restart anymore and the log tells me this:

```
You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
```

Is there anything I'm missing to edit?

Comment: Please share full `sites-available/000-default.conf`.

Comment: You need to provide more information than that. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very self-describing: you have only configured port, not TLS. You should start by reading [SSL/TLS Strong Encryption: How-To](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

> Your SSL configuration will need to contain, at minimum, the following
>   directives.
>
> ```
> LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
>
> Listen 443 
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     SSLEngine on
>     SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
>     SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key" 
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

You are using a distribution where configuration is split to different files on different folders, so it is not wise to add this all to `httpd.conf`or `apache2.conf`, but to destinations where they are included from.

You were modifying **default non-ssl site** from `sites-available/`, but they are actually included from `sites-enabled/` where they get symlinked with `a2ensite` (or `ln -s`). Like `sites-available/default` is linked to `sites-enabled/000-default`, sample configuration in `sites-available/default-ssl` should be modified and then linked in `sites-enabled/000-default-ssl`. Similarly, `LoadModule` comes from `modules-enabled/` after creating a symlink to `modules-available/` with command `a2enmod ssl`.

But of course that's not all. TLS also needs the certificate and key, and they are not just lines in a configuration file, but needs to be created and signed. So **yes, you are missing quite a lot**.

For lazy people, there's all kind of tutorials like this [Enable SSL for Apache server in 5 minutes](https://hallard.me/enable-ssl-for-apache-server-in-5-minutes/). Despite from 2012-2014, it seems mostly accurate. Probably the manual of your distribution of choice has an own page for this, too, which would be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Just running port 443 doesn't implement HTTPS; it just tells Apache to listen on that port. You need to tell it to use SSL for that virtual host, and to supply the necessary SSL parameters.

For example, for a web site called "www.mysite.org", with the web site root at /var/www/vhost/www.mysite.org/ and certificate keys stored under "/etc/pki/tls/", you would create a configuration file like this:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mysite.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/www.mysite.org/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/www.mysite.org.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/www.mysite.org.key"

    # This implements weaker encryption, use it if you have old web clients that can't handle modern strong encryption
    #SSLProtocol      all -SSLv3
    #SSLCipherSuite   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5

    # This implements strong encryption, disabling everything but TLSv1.2 (and 1.3 when that is implemented)
    SSLProtocol      all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCipherSuite   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
</VirtualHost>
```

You might not need the first line if your Apache configuration loads the ssl module by default (as it probably would). I've also given you two choices for the encryption strengths, with the weaker set commented out. Adjust as appropriate. There are other things you can do to enhance the security (e.g. use of HSTS) and customise the site as well if you wish, but you can look those up for yourself if necessary.

(If you're interested, a good reference for SSL security can be found at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS.)